# Matching local Python environment to Google Colab's

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a python project that works locally in Google Colab. To do so, I have used the command `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`  to extract my local dependencies to then, using `!pip install -r requirements.txt`, install them into this new environment. Nevertheless, I find that, even after running that, I get errors on missing libraries. For instance, I have the following lines in my `requirements.txt`
`pyperclip==1.8.2 python-dotenv==1.0.0`

But when running the code in colab I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'`, and if I manually execute the line `!pip install python-dotenv==1.0.0`, the problem is fixed.

I'd like to know how to replicate exactly my local environment in the remote one, having the same Python version as well as the exact same versions of each library being used in order to have exactly the same execution in both environments.

I also tried to extract the dependencies both from pip and pip3 in case some dependencies were imported with one tool and others with another one, by doing
`pip freeze > pip_packages.txt pip3 freeze > pip3_packages.txt cat pip_packages.txt pip3_packages.txt > requirements.txt`

but the result was the same.